# java token if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, stringtokenizer

I have a problem with an ifstatement in a StringTokenizer method i think it is due to it being a char array, I have tryed to convert it but it seems not to work any help would be aprecheated thanks harry.

```
char[] password = loginPass.getPassword();
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(theText, ",");
if (thisToken.equals(password))
{
      System.out.println("Hi Harry u got the pasword right!!!");

}
```

Comment: You need to tell us at least what the type of "thisToken" is.

Comment: Im new to this kind of think ive added some code but im not sure where i would finde out what type it is

Comment: Dear @Ste_T, do you know that, as Java is a typed language supporting exceptions, if you don"'t give us the type of `thisToken` and the exception or error that happens when you execute this code, we will be totally unable to help you ?

Comment: char[] is the type of "password".  StringTokenizer is the type of the variable "st"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that a `char[]` will never equal a `String`.

You could try

```
if (thisToken.equals(new String(password)))
```

If `thisToken` actually happens to be a `char[]` too, then you probably want to use `Arrays.equals(thisToken, password)` to compare the content of the arrays.